# CalendarDatePickerDialog on Activity without support package

Tags: android, android-support-library, fragmentmanager

I'm using `CalendarDatePickerDialog` from [BetterPickers](https://github.com/derekbrameyer/android-betterpickers) in my project, 
if i use a `FragmentActivity`, then i can use the `getSupportFragmentManager()`.

The problem is that i'm trying to add [CWAC-Camera](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera) as well,
 but for that i need to use
`getFragmentManager()` in a regular `Activity` which breaks the `BettePickers`.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try to extends FragmentActivity and implements CalendarDatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener

Change your Activity to FragmentActivity.

Use the newInstance(YouActivity.this)

Enjoy!